# How to edit the *compilation* buffer in Emacs

Tags: emacs, compilation

When I compile in emacs, it opens a new buffer called *compilation*, and displays the errors.  Sometimes the errors are long and hard to read, so I'd like to be able to edit the text (mostly be choosing my own line breaks at pertinent points).  Is there a way to do this and continue using the buffer to jump to the next error (and keep the buffer's default highlighting)?

I can copy-paste the whole thing into another buffer, but that's a lot of overhead, and gets tedious as I try to find where the next error is in the pasted version.

Comment: I usually make it writable using `C-x C-q` and insert new lines with `C-q C-j`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `toggle-read-only` command by typing <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-q</kbd>.

Then change to fundamental mode with <kbd>M-x</kbd>`fundamental-mode`<kbd>RET</kbd>

After editing, you can go into compilation-minor-mode with
<kbd>M-x</kbd>`compilation-minor-mode`<kbd>RET</kbd> and switch back and forth as needed.